# What happened to the "Detach All" option in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm used to using the "Detach All" function on the debug menu to allow me to go back to editing and compiling, with the intent of re-attaching later.

This menu option disappeared on me after I installed Windows 7 64-bit. I've heard from others that it didn't exist under 32-bit Vista, either.

For the record, the option appears when debugging console apps. So far, I've only noticed it missing on web applications.

Edit: So, if I debug just a simple web application with nothing else in it, the Detach All option is there. Need to find out what is different about the (multiple) projects I've been **trying** to debug that don't have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing that can prevent detaching from the process is mixed-mode debugging. I don't have much experience with web debugging, but if the debugger is attaching to the IIS process or something, it seems like the debugging mode could be related.

Anyway, is it possible that you're doing mixed-mode debugging (rather than native-only or managed-only) by accident?

Comment: can you explain why mixed mode debugging prevents detaching? "stop debugging" option seems to kill my process

Answer (score 3):

You can add it

1. Click the down arrow on the debug toolbar to select Add or Remove Buttons > Customize
2. Click Add Command
3. Select Debug from the right menu
4. Select "Detach All" from the commands options on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I have Detach All in my VS when I'm debugging a web application and I'm running Win 7 x64.

Are you sure it isn't a Web Site project? Maybe that would be the issue.